# _block_type_is_valid(phead- nblockuse) when using delete[]

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>

    class SDAL{
        private:
            int capacity;
            int tail;
            int head;
            T * arrayList;
        public:
            SDAL();
            SDAL(int capacity);
            ~SDAL();
            const T& replace(const T& t, int position);
            void insert(const T& t, int position);
            void push_back(const T& item);
            void push_front(const T& item);
            const T& remove(const int& position);
            const T& pop_back();
            const T& pop_front();
            const T& item_at(int position);
            bool isEmpty() const;
            int size() const;
            void clear();
            //bool contains(const T& t, equals function)
            void print() const;
    };

    template<typename T>
    SDAL<T>::SDAL(){
        this->capacity = 50;
        this->tail = -1;
        this->head = -1;
        arrayList = new T[capacity];
    }

    template<typename T>
    SDAL<T>::SDAL(int capacity){
        this->capacity = capacity;
        this->tail = -1;
        this->head = -1;
        arrayList = new T[capacity];
    }

    template<typename T>
    SDAL<T>::~SDAL(){
        delete[] arrayList;
    }

    template<typename T>
    int SDAL<T>::size() const{
        return (tail + 1);
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool SDAL<T>::isEmpty() const{
        return (tail == -1);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void SDAL<T>::push_back(const T& item){
        if (isEmpty()){
            arrayList[0] = item;
            tail = 0;
            head = 0;
        }
        else if (tail < capacity - 1){
            ++tail;
            arrayList[tail] = item;
        }
        else{
            int newCapacity = capacity * 1.5;
            T * newArrayList = new T[newCapacity];
            for (int i = 0; i <= tail; ++i){
                newArrayList[i] = arrayList[i];
            }
            ++tail;
            newArrayList[tail] = item;
            capacity = newCapacity;
            arrayList = newArrayList;
            delete[] newArrayList;
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void SDAL<T>::push_front(const T& item){
        if (isEmpty()){
            arrayList[0] = item;
            tail= 0;
            head = 0;
        }
        else if (tail < capacity){
            T *newArrayList = new T[capacity];
            newArrayList[head] = item;

            if (tail == 0){
                newArrayList[1] = arrayList[0];
            }
            else{

                for (int i = 0; i <= tail; ++i){
                    newArrayList[i+1] = arrayList[i];
                }
            }

            ++tail;
            arrayList = newArrayList;
        }
        else{
            int newCapacity = capacity * 1.5;
            T * newArrayList = new T[newCapacity];

            newArrayList[head] = item;
            for (int i = 0; i <= tail; ++i){
                newArrayList[i+1] = arrayList[i];
            }

            ++tail;
            capacity = newCapacity;
            arrayList = newArrayList;
            delete[] newArrayList;
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void SDAL<T>::print() const{
        for (int i = 0; i <= tail; ++i){
            cout << " " << arrayList[i];
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Head = " << head << endl;
        cout << "Tail = " << tail << endl;
    }

int main() 
{

    SDAL<char> list(5);

    list.push_back('a');
    list.push_back('b');
    list.push_back('c');
    list.push_front('d');
    list.push_front('e');
    list.push_front('f');
    list.push_front('g');

    list.print();

    cout << list.size() << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I have tried everything but I can not figure out why I am getting this problem. When I initialize my array I pass in a `int` capacity depending on the size of that capacity the array is dynamically allocated using `arrayList = new T[capacity]`.

After the program is executed the destructor is called to `delete[] arrayList`. However when the program runs I get the error `_block_type_is_valid(phead- nblockuse)` I don't understand why this is happening please help!

If I increase the size of capacity, when initializing, greater than the amount of elements I am trying to add to my `arrayList` I do not receive the error message. Am I not managing my memory correctly?

I can not use vectors for this class.

Comment: Short answer: use `std::vector`. Long answer: don't ignore the Rule of Three (or Five), and once you've done that, spend enough time making sure the code actually works after, including exceptions.

Comment: you are stomping on memory somehow, using released memory, releasing things you didnt allocate, releasing twice,....

Comment: Use the debugger.  You can't write code like this and expect things to go smoothly, which is why you should use the debugger to step through your program to see where the problem is.

Comment: I used the degbugger and everything runs smoothly until the code reaches the delete[] arrayList

Comment: @KenanTufekci The debugger isn't there to just run your code.  You should *step through* your program and inspect the flow, look at the value of variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your following line is causing the problem in couple of methods of your class.

```
 arrayList = newArrayList;
   delete[] newArrayList;
```

It should be

```
delete[] arrayList;
arrayList = newArrayList;
```

When you are expanding your memory, first the steps should be:

1. Allocate bigger memory.
2. Copy the existing blocks into the bigger memory.
3. Delete the Older Memory using the main pointer variable.
4. Assign the new Pointer into the main pointer.

But ideally we should be using the `std::vector<T>` if possible instead of ours own.

Comment: delete[] arraylist    arrayList =newArrayList I get HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED

Answer (score 0):

First obvious error:

```
else if (tail < capacity)
{
    T *newArrayList = new T[capacity];
    newArrayList[head] = item;

    if (tail == 0)
        newArrayList[1] = arrayList[0];
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= tail; ++i)
            newArrayList[i + 1] = arrayList[i];
    }
    ++tail;
    arrayList = newArrayList;  // <<-- memory leak

}
```

In the code above, you failed to `delete []` the original `arrayList`, thus you have a memory leak.

Second error:

```
    arrayList = newArrayList;  // <-- you copied allocated pointer here
    delete[] newArrayList;     // <-- now you've deleted it here!
```

You've just deleted the memory you allocated.  It should be:

```
    delete [] arrayList;
    arrayList = newArrayList;
```

There are more errors, than this, but these are the obvious ones.

The other thing is that you seem to not able to make up your mind whether what you have is a linked list, or just a reinvention of `std::vector`.  Why do you have `head` and `tail` here?  Why not two simple int member variables to tell you:

1) How many items in the array you have now (i.e. the size() of the array), and

2) The max capacity that the array can hold.

Once you reimplement things this way, it gets much easier.  All of this `-1` stuff is throwing you off, and I would even bet is causing a lot of grief with the heap corruption issues.

Also, your `push_front` function should be copying the array elements starting from the back and working to the front.  For example:

```
for (int i = tail - 1; i >= 0;  --i)
    arrayList[i+1] = arrayList[i];
arrayList[0] = item;
```

This assumes that `capacity` hasn't been exceeded.

Comment: I have replaced all the location where I need to delete the original arrayList  with    delete[] arrayList;   arrayList = newArrayList    however when the debugger reached the delete[] arrayList I get HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED

Comment: When I comment out the delete[] arrayList in the destructor the program runs fine, but don't i need to have a delete[] arrayList since i dynamically allocated arrayList in my constructor with arrayList = new T[capacity]?? why wont it let the destructor delete the class member??

Comment: I pointed out the obvious errors.  Regardless of what you're seeing now, you must make the fixes above.  Second, your code to allocate more memory is overly convoluted.  Second, why is there an explicit check for `isEmpty`?  Why does it matter, as long as you haven't exceeded capacity?

Comment: @KenanTufekci - `why wont it let the destructor delete the class member?? `  The reason is that you mismanaged your pointers.  C++ doesn't tell you when you do this, that's why you need to use the debugger and step through your program.

Comment: @KenanTufekci - Take a look at this sample here: http://ideone.com/ET33AB  Note that `push_back` becomes "easier", and the `push_front` uses what was stated in my answer.  The sample removes the `head` and `tail` stuff you're doing, and uses simple variables to track the current size and capacity.  No need to check for `isEmpty` before adding an item to the list.